# Let me know how to make html to show some response values

Tags: python, html, request

I would like to make some codes that make a html file for showing some response values.
So I made codes as below. However I got systaxError.
Can you let me know some advice for resolving it?

```
import requests
import os

URL = 'https://www.example'
response = requests.get(URL)

file=open('test.html','w',encoding='UTF-8')
file.write("<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>"response.text"</body></html>")
file.closeenter code here
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The interpreter should show you the place where you have an error. If you can't resolve it, please share the whole error, so we know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file.write method is wrong use an f string instead

```
import requests
import os

URL = 'https://www.example'
response = requests.get(URL)

file=open('test.html','w',encoding='UTF-8')
file.write(f"<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>{response.text}</body></html>")
```